# Ramda: Call array of functions on array of values

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

If I have the array `data` and the array of functions `[fn1, fn2, fn3]`, what's the right way with Ramda to get

```
[fn1(data[0]), fn2(data[1], fn3(data[2]), ...]
```

Basically, I want to call each function with the value that shares an array index in the `data` as its parameter, and get an array of the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use [`zipWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) with [`call`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#call):

```
R.zipWith(R.call, fns, data)
```